# How do I run a Chow test for structural break over time in panel data?

Tags: r, time-series, panel-data

I hope somebody could help me with my problem in using R. I'm performing an analysis by using panel data from different countries and years. The time span I'm considering is 2002-2015 for 165 countries and I would like to show that a structural break in my data occurs in a year between 2007 and 2009, in coincidence with the financial crisis.

I already found a function in the "plm" package called "pooltest" but that doesn't help me in understanding where the structural break is. In addition, even though "pooltest" is described as a Chow test function, it seems not to specifically deal with structural breaks over a time period. Does somebody have any other idea? I would be very grateful for your help! Thank you in advance.

```
sub1 <- subset(mydata2, years_panel > "2001" & years_panel < "2016")
sub1_def <- match_df(sub1, reg1[,1])
sub1_panel <- pdata.frame(sub1_def, index = c("CountryName", "years_panel"))

plm_fxef1 <- plm(GDPPC_panel ~ privcred_panel, data=sub1_panel, model= "within")
summary(plm_fxef1)
pooltest(GDPPC_panel ~ privcred_panel, data = sub1_panel, model = "within")
```

I read the documentation for "pooltest" and I'm not sure that this is the function that fits my problem. I'm just getting a F-statistic and no indicaton about where the break could be.

Comment: I suggest to consider the `strucchange` package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/strucchange/vignettes/strucchange-intro.pdf

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried to give it a look. The problem is that such package only works for normal regressions. It doesn't fit panel data